# PK Entity classes when generate entities from tables

Tags: mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, many-to-many, entity-relationship

When i generate a many to many entity from a many to many table from db eclipse creates a PK class where there are hash functions. 
What are the meaning of PK classes? Are them an error of index or something in table creation? How can i manage them?
I used MySqlWorkbench to create tables.